# Difference in available MoveIt API's

Tags: moveit, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I have a question regarding the general use of the MoveIT C++ / Python / Command Shell API(s) in context wth the provided launch files of the ros industrial program for fanuc robots. My goal is to plan paths and avoid obstacles with the Fanuc M20IA35M robot.

After starting the launch files to talk to the fanuc_driver on the robot...

1. Do I have to start a move_group node myself to send a) motion requests or to b) monitor the robot in rviz?
2. I am not sure if I really understand the differences between a) moveit_commander(Shell / API?) b) capabilities of Python / C++ API from moveit.

It seems to me that there are a lot of ways to achieve my path planning goal and I am a little unsure where to start.

Thanks in advance for any comments!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/327017/difference-in-available-moveit-api%27s/) by [cpetersmeier](https://answers.ros.org/users/43529/cpetersmeier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2019-06-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After some work with the MoveIt Software I have come to a conclusion, which I present here for future reference:

1. The MoveGroup Node represents an entity of MoveIt. Whenever one wants to use MoveIt functionality, the MoveGroup Node has to be started. The ROS-Industrial foundation provides the `moveit_planning_execution.launch` file for that. Monitoring the Robot in Rviz without motion planning functionality is therefore possible without starting the MoveGroup Node.
2. There are multiple ways to "talk to" or use the functionality of MoveIt. The `MoveIt Commander` shell is a quick way to interact with the model via the command line, but most of the high level functions can be also accessed via the `MoveGroup C++ Interface`. If one wants to go in depth an use the software adapters of MoveIt directly to for example call custom designed planners, there is the `Motion Planning API`.

---

Originally posted by [cpetersmeier](https://answers.ros.org/users/43529/cpetersmeier/) with karma: 35 on 2019-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-07-09**:\

> The ROS-Industrial foundation provides the `trajectory_execution.launch` file for that.

I believe you are confusing this with `moveit_planning_execution.launch`.

`trajectory_execution.launch.xml` is a MoveIt internal file that is only ever included in other `.launch` files.

**Comment by [cpetersmeier](https://answers.ros.org/users/43529/cpetersmeier/) on 2019-07-09**:
Thats correct, edited the mistake.